# Adding a new entry to a multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

All the examples that I have seen on this site suggest that I should be able to do this:

```
var multiArray = []
var singleArray = []

singleArray[0] = "10"
singleArray[1] = "11"

multiArray.push(singleArray)

singleArray[0] = "20"
singleArray[1] = "21"

multiArray.push(singleArray)
```

and I would expect multiArray to contain:

```
["10", "11"]["20", "21"}
```

In fact it contains:

```
["20", "21"]["20", "21"}
```

It looks as though multiArray holds a reference to singleArray rather than the data. So changing the contents of singleArray affects both entries in multiArray.

Have I made a very basic error or is there some workaround for this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference, so you're modifying the original array. Just create another one and you'll be fine

Comment: FWIW: `multiArray.push([10,11], [20,21])`. *"It looks as though multiArray holds a reference to singleArray rather than the data."* Yep, your are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an object reference problem - Arrays are objects, so when you modify [0] and [1], you're modifying it in both places.
Use a slice to copy the contents:

```
var multiArray = [],
  singleArray = [];

singleArray[0] = "10";
singleArray[1] = "11";

multiArray.push(singleArray.slice(0));

singleArray[0] = "20";
singleArray[1] = "21";

multiArray.push(singleArray);

console.log(multiArray); // [["10", "11"], ["20", "21"]]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the best practice for a simple array.

Answer (score 1):

You're not pushing in a copy of the array. You're pushing in a copy of the *reference* to the array. Since the copies all point to the same array, you are seeing it twice.

You can simply do this:

```
multiArray.push([10,11], [20,21])
```

<s>Another way is to do this:</s>

```
multiArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(singleArray)));
```

Here you're stringifying the array and then parsing it again, in effect creating a new array. A kind of "cloning", if you will.

Using `slice` is a better alternative for this particular scenario:

```
multiArray.push(singleArray.slice(0));
```

Comment: Array.prototype.slice(0) is far better for a simple Array, plus JSON isn't even defined on a lot of non ECMA5 browsers.

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles Maybe you should take a look at [this](http://caniuse.com/json) for JSON support. Yes, `slice` is better; I didn't notice it in the original question.

Comment: IE 6 and 7, yeah, exactly. Do you want to totally fail on 3.5% of users?? Also, that's just a terrible way to clone a simple array in general. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles Sure, if you want to support browsers that the vendors themselves have dropped support for. There are hundreds of things that don't work on IE 6 and 7; `JSON` is the least of them. Seriously; 3.5%? If you're still browsing the web on IE 6 and 7 expect to have a lot of things broken. Unless you're using it because of a legacy application you really shouldn't be using IE 6 or 7 to browser the web. I'm not going to spend 95% of my time trying to ensure browser compatibility for 3.5%

Comment: At scale for an enterprise? - 3.5% of internet users are a huge deal. Also, that's just a really bad way to clone a single dimensional array. Why wouldn't you use slice? It's the shortest, smallest, most canonical and readable way to clone. 3.5% of users on a large site could mean 10's of millions in revenue - you can hire a lot of devs and still cover that cost, that's why even a team of 5 working full-time to support them is still a good idea.

Comment: Hey if you want to slap a sticker on your site that says "Works on IE 6 and 7" go right ahead, but I don't think it's worth it to spend a ton of time taking into account quirks for browsers that are more than 10 years old *even at enterprise* which happens to be my day job. We don't write any code to support IE 6 or 7 and recommend that our users upgrade. No argument on cloning the array.

Comment: It's a question of economics for a site of any reasonable size, and getting used to supporting legacy is a good idea, since we'll be having the same argument about ECMA6 in a couple years. We're living in a golden age of compliance right now, but at the next major bump my argument will be even more compelling.

Comment: Well then let's all support punch cards, because you know, legacy. Seriously - at some point the costs of supporting legacy features outweigh the benefits. That's when you cut the cord. That time is here for IE 6 and 7. IE 6 came out **12** years ago.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my argument - Salesforce.com supports IE6 for 95% of features (only some of Chatter doesn't carry) because their IE6 users offer tons of revenue. That's a big, well-respected company with a browser strategy of support rather than forced upgrades. You don't have to like it, but it's a reality of developing for any large company.

Comment: "Salesforce.com supports IE6 for 95% of features [...] *because their IE6 users offer tons of revenue*" - that is the only reason. You can't make a blanket statement that says "support everything all the time". It depends on the cost-to-benefit ratio. Salesforce *has* a bunch of customers who use IE 6 because most of their customers are corporations with a huge amount of investment in legacy tech (especially ActiveX). These things only work in IE6. It completely depends on your customer profile.

Comment: I never said support everything all the time. This is a trivial sized snippet of code to make totally IE6 compliant, so why not do it, especially when it's the most concise and readable solution??

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles Then we were off on scope; I was talking about using these features in general. I used `JSON` because I didn't even think about using `slice`. I wasn't evangelizing one over the other. Also `JSON` is pretty much widely-supported *except* in legacy browsers; it really isn't bleeding-edge. IE 6 compliance doesn't run through my mind and it hasn't run through my mine in *years*. While in general I agree that it is better to write code that is as widely supported as possible, I don't think it is a given. Modern browsers have a host of new features that makes writing JS *easier*.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this and get what you want . . . the other two answers will do it, as will these two approaches:

```
multiArray.push(["10", "11"]);
multiArray.push(["20", "21"]);
```

. . . and . . .

```
multiArray.push(new Array("10", "11"));
multiArray.push(new Array("20", "21"));
```

Both result in an array of: `[["10", "11"], ["20", "21"]]`

In the end, the important thing is that you need to create a new array instance for each set of values that you store, since the outer array will just be storing pointers to each inner array that it contains.

Comment: Why not slice? He said he wants to use the singleArray

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles . . . slice would work fine too (that's why I said `the other two answers will do it` at the beginning of my answer).  Where did he say that he wants to use a single array?  I just see that he happened to use one in the original post . . .

Comment: Why have we all gotten downvotes?  All of these approaches solve the issue that he is seeing . . .

Comment: The JSON one is totally bad form and fails on 3.5% of browsers online, and using a totally new array is bad because it requires creation of a new array instance every time you want to push. Idk why mine, slice is the best-practice for a single dimensional clone.

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles - HTML5 fails on a lot more than 3.5% of browsers, but a lot of people still use it.   ;)   I wasn't saying that the JSON approach was *THE* solution or that I would even use it, but it will do the job in a lot of instances.  As for my answers, I was just showing an alternate ways of accomplishing what he appears to be trying do.  I didn't see any requirement to use a single array to store the values, so I provided some other approaches.

Comment: Your approach also makes for larger code, and the guy is a newbie - your answer is a lot better than JSON, but showing a newbie anything other than the very standard, compliant and compact best practice is inadvisable. It's not wrong, but it's not what you should teach a new guy as a pattern. Cheers ! :)

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles - you're willing to make a lot more assumptions about his situation than I am.  :D  He asked why it was behaving that way and the general response (accurately) was because pushing the array creates a pointer to it.  I thought my way was the most straightforward way of illustrating that the stored arrays have to be unique and independent.  `.slice()` may be the most efficient, but it's certainly not the most intuitive way of explaining why his code wasn't working (especially to a new guy . . . shoot, I didn't know what `.slice()` did when I first got started  LOL  ).

Comment: @VivinPaliath - I up-voted both of you . . . all three answers address his question accurately.   :)

Comment: You didn't know because nobody told you the best, they gave answers like you and the other guy...

Comment: LOL . . . you're taking this way too personally.   The OP now knows 4 different ways to avoid the issue that he was seeing and has an understanding of why he was seeing it.  I'd say that he is better off having learned all of the options, personally.